# Creating first image on bluemix docker

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to create a simple ubuntu image on docker within Bluemix.
I have the cli setup (at the latest version) but keep getting a login prompt when trying to push the image.

My dockerfile is trivial:

```
FROM docker.io/ubuntu:latest 
MAINTAINER My Name
RUN echo "Imaged" > /tmp/image.txt
```

I build it with 
`sudo docker build -t ubuntu`

then tag it with

```
sudo docker tag ubuntu registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/MYNAMESPACE/ubuntu
```

I login with

```
cf login
```

Then push with

```
[ibmcloud@analyticsadmin docker]$ sudo docker push registry.ng.bluemix.net/MYNAMESPACE/ubuntu
The push refers to a repository [registry.ng.bluemix.net/MYNAMESPACE/ubuntu] (len: 1)
Sending image list

Please login prior to push:
Username:
```

I'm new to bluemix/docker so user error is highly likely. Can you spot my error? My DOCKER* environment variables are set as appropriate for my bluemix container service.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed the step to login to the IBM Containers registry, that's why `docker push` is asking you for the `username`.

After `cf login` you have to run the following command as well:

```
$ cf ic login
```

This will authenticate you to the IBM Containers registry so you can push your images.

Please note that `ic` is a plugin you have to install for the `cf` command line interface. If you have not installed it yet please see instructions in the following link:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_cfic.html#container_cli_cfic_install

For example to install plugin in Linux system run the following command:

```
$ cf install-plugin https://static-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibm-containers-linux_x64
```

Answer (score 0):

A typo I see in your commands is that you tag your container for sending it to the UK data center (eu-gb) then try to push it to the south US one (ng), that's why I think the second command asks you to login.